# How to manage opengl shader correctly?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I want to some objects using shader. I name these objects obj_1, obj_2, ...obj_n.
One object's data stores in one vbo. I name these vbos vbo_1, vbo_2, ...vbo_n.
I need use vertex shader, geometry shader , and fragment shader for every object.
All vertex shader is just multiple the vertex with a modelviewprojectoin matrix.
All fragment shader is just set the color.
However, every geometry shader is different.

Here is my planA:
I create one program. The vertex shader has a uniform variable named ModelViewProjection. The fragment shader has a uniform variable named color.
In the loop of all objects, I set the vertex shader's ModelViewProjection uniform variable and set the fragment shader's color uniform variable.
Then change the geometry shader using corresponding GLSL code.
However, I can not find a way to replace the geometry shader in a program　while changing vertex shader and fragment shader unchanged.

So I have a planB:
I create lots of programs as many as objects. It is feasible. 
However, it means that the varialbe shader and fragment shader is repeated as many as numbers of objects. It is a waste of space and it's hard to expand.
So my question is, is there a plan C for my case? Or that there is a way to change geometry shader in program?

Comment: *"repeated many times"* *"waste of space"*, can you elaborate on this? you don't need to copy vertex and fragment shaders to use them in different programs

Comment: A shader object can be "used" in multiple program objects. And note, there is the possibility of [Separate programs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Separate_programs). See also [GLSL Separate Program Multi Stage](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Example/GLSL_Separate_Program_Multi_Stage)

Comment: "repeated many times" means I create the same shader many times. There are memory to store the same shader.  
Now I know don't need to copy the shader,  thanks.